# tar only *.log files and delete orginals when finished

Tags: shell, tar

I am using the following script to create a tarball of a directory with php

```
exec("tar -zcvf archive_name.tar.gz *");
```

and this is working as expected, but I would like to extend this code so that it will only add files to the tarball that have a certain extension (*.log in this case) then delete the originals after the tarball has been created. Any advise or examples would be great.

TIA,
Kevin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change you command to:

```
exec("tar -zcvf archive_name.tar.gz *.log && rm -f *.log")
```

Changes made:

- Instead of passing all file (`*`) as
  argument to `tar` we now pass `*.log`
- Added `&& rm -f *.log`. The command
  `rm -f *.log` forcefully deletes all
  `.log` files from the present working
  directory. We've used an `&&` as the
  glue between the two commands because
  we want the files to be deleted **only
  after** the tarball is created.

Comment: thanks, yours and tom's answers are almost exactly the same minus the -f switch which I guess is needed so thx again.

Comment: @Kevin: You are welcome. Do look at @Elzo Valugi's answer which looks better as it is portable. Also don't forget to accept the answer which helped you the most.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really relevant to php, seeing as you're just escaping out to a shell command anyway. Try

```
exec("tar -zcvf archive_name.tar.gz *.log && rm *.log");
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be on serverfault. Tar is a linux program. If you want to do the same in pure PHP you can use [glob](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) and [Zend_Filter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.set.html#zend.filter.set.compress.tar) tar adapter:

```
$files = glob("*.log");
foreach($files as $file) {
    $filter     = new Zend_Filter_Compress(array(
         'adapter' => 'tar',
         'options' => array(
            'archive' => 'filename.bz2'
         ),
    ));
    $compressed = $filter->filter($file);
}
```